# Preg matching random text from html source code using PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, preg-match, text-extraction

I have website and it's source html code looks something like below.

```
<li class="item" xx-href-xx="http://xx.xx/s/randomtext/randomtext?NOTradnomtext" yy-href-gg="http://xx.xx/X/RANDOMTEXTWHATIWANT/STILLRADNOMTEXTWHATIWANT?NOTradnomtext" data="212123134" data-title="TITLE">
  <a class="front" href="#" xx-href="http://xx.xx/s/randomtext/randomtext?NOTradnomtext">
    <img src="http://photo.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="cock">
        <div class="action"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="label">
    <div>
         <h3 class="title">Example</h3>
         <p>2013-10-25 : 03:35</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</li>

... And so on same kind of classes (only titles and texts changing) ...
```

How to preg_match yy-href-gg="http://xx.xx/X/**TEXTWHATIWANT/TEXTWHATIWANT**?NOTradnomtext from all of those records and include also title for result. So result should look in this case something like that

- Example
  TEXTWHATIWANT/TEXTWHATIWANT
- Example2
  TEXTWHATIWANT/TEXTWHATIWANT

and so on.

Comment: See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Okay... Is there any good way to do that then, I can't have any json formatted version of that data. Is only way to do it manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use character classes and negated character classes to match characters that are or are not what you allow.  Use `\K` to forget any matched characters so that you only get back the desired portion of text as the fullstring match (no capture groups).

I assume that your url path is relatively safe to match non-slash, non-double-quote, and non-question-mark characters between directory slashes.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FVHgA))

```
preg_match_all(
    '# [a-z]{2}-href-[a-z]{2}="https?://[^/"?]+/[^/"?]+/\K[^/"?]+/[^/"?]+#i',
    $html,
    $matches
);
var_export($matches[0]);
```